# How do I remove lazyloading on the mh-spotlight-widget

Tags: widgets, post-thumbnails, performance

What is the easiest way to disable native lazy load without a plugin for a specific widget in WordPress? I can't find anything at all about this question that I could use for `functions.php`?

```php
// XX = placeholder for specified image number
// widget class = mh-spotlight-widget
    
function no_lazy_load_image( $value, $image, $context ) {
    if ( 'the_content' === $context AND 'class_name' === 'mh-spotlight-widget' ) {
        $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url( XX, 'large' ); 
        if ( false !== strpos( $image, ' src="' . $image_url . '"' )) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return $value;
}
add_filter( 'wp_img_tag_add_loading_attr', 'no_lazy_load_image', XX, XX );
```

Could something like this be adapted, to work for all images in the `mh-spotlight-widget` widget, or at least as a combination of image or and widget?

Comment: What do you mean by a specific class? Image tags with specific CSS class names?

Comment: thanks for asking: I mean the class of the widget; because the image in the widget is used on several places; I only try to disable lazy load for (changing) images in a specific widget on the front/hompeage

Comment: what kind of widget?

Comment: mh-spotlight-widget

Comment: this widget seems to be behind a paywall, so Im not sure whats the best way here. Maybe the authors can help.

Comment: So it seems it is not possible to add a class (the class of the widget) with something like

Comment: hmmm... so I understand right that something like the snippet I have added in the question (which is not working) cannot be enhanced by adding a widget class?

Comment: Would it be more accurate to say your question is actually: _"How do I remove lazyloading on the mh-spotlight-widget?"_. It looks like classes are just an X Y problem, an attempted solution at what you actually want. Make sure your question contains everything it needs to be answered, and use the `Edit` link under the tags to add information

Comment: @TomJNowell you are 100 % right, have adapted the question

Comment: it looks like it's this widget: https://mhthemes.com/support/knb/custom-widgets/#mh-spotlight Note that there is a chance a generic general WP solution may not be possible, and it might require knowledge of how that widget works internally. If so you won't be able to ask about it on this site.